SSGs with "dynamic" content
I'm trying to create a blog with static pages.
That's when i learned about SSG such as Hugo and Zola. Here's my question, imagine i want to have a "recent articles" section and a "correlated articles" section, which i need to change "automatically" on the blog building phase based on data i have on the db(such as tags, category, key words ecc..which i insert manually).And in the future i will want users to be able to login for a comments section.
Are SSGs such as Hugo or Zola a good choice for my case? If not what's the correct approach to my idea.
Thanks.

Hugo is a great choice for any website... however, you should know that related posts and comments might require some trickery. I would investigate that before proceeding.
